# Are there any purely local source control clients?

Tags: version-control

The company I work for uses TFS for its version control and has quite a strong opinion on data security.

With that in mind I'm unable to use source control services such as git due the capability being there to push your work to an external source.

My question is are there any git-like ways to manage your code which are PURELY LOCAL and do not offer the ability to push your changes to the internet? TFS does not seem to offer much in the way of local commits.

I've been told there's the shelving function however as a junior dev I would rather make any accessible code be in good standard before others can see it.

Thanks

Comment: Both RCS and SCCS are now old, but they are local-only systems.  I still use RCS (I migrated from SCCS prior to Y2K because the RCS format already used 4-digit years and SCCS did not, though in some ways I prefer SCCS).  You can find GNU's CSSC (complement of SCCS) and RCS.  It won't affect you, but I have some old RCS files that the new RCS 5.9.x doesn't like (4 files out of multiple thousand, and all more than 15 years old).  RCS 5.7 was the stable version for a long, long time.  SCCS is standardized by POSIX, but most of the world has moved to distributed VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm unable to use source control services such as git due the capability being there to push your work to an external source

That sounds like a rather odd reason. Even if you use a source control tool that does not support publishing the stuff, there is nothing that prevents you from simply uploading the contents manually somewhere. Sure, it requires manual work, but even that you could automate without introducing a version control system that does it.

The way you explain this also sounds as if you do have some kind of control of the tool you may end up using for this, so the company needs to trust you anyway to not publish the stuff.

And at that point, there is no reason not to use Git here: After all, it works completely offline, and you *do not* have to set up a remote which you could push to.

Taking things even further, if your company works with TFS, then you could utilize [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) which is a bridge between Git and TFS. With it, you can actually connect to your TFS, use Git locally, and then publish your changes (after you polished them) to the TFS. So it would all be a single integrated workflow, without you having to juggle between two different incompatible systems: You just commit using Git, and once you have a set of commits ready for checking them into the TFS, you can e.g. do `git tfs checkin` and make a single check-in for it.

> I've been told there's the shelving function

The TFS shelvesets are also not offline; they are public in the same way the normal checkins are, it’s just that they live on the side without affecting the normal TFS repository. And they are quite cumbersome to work with too (since they don’t give you a history).

Comment: I wasn't aware that git could be used with TFS, thanks! It certainly seems like the best possible solution. I'll query and see if I can use it.